# setSelectionFromTop sometimes working and sometimes not

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

I have following code to calculate list scroll position before list update and to return to the original position. I would like to align based on the last item visible on the listview.

- `mList` is the list that I'm trying to keep the scroll position.
- `isScrolling` is the function that returns if the user is manually scrolling the listview.
- `mAssocPage.mListPosition` is a class that has scroll information.
- - `.selectionBase` is the object in `mAssocPage.arrItems` which is used as basis for calculating the scroll position.
- - `.nPosExtra` is the top value of the last visible item in the listview.

This function is called in mList's OnScrollListener and thus will always contain the position of the listview.

From https://github.com/GaulSori/artwave/blob/master/src/gaulsori/artwave/ui/activity/main/SinglePageView.java

```
public synchronized void calculateListPosition(){
    int nItemIndex=mList.getLastVisiblePosition()-mAdapter.getPaddingCount()-1;

    //Is there something to align?
    if(0<=nItemIndex && nItemIndex<mAssocPage.arrItems.size()){
        mAssocPage.mListPosition.setAtBottom(false);
        mAssocPage.mListPosition.selectionBase=mAssocPage.arrItems.get(nItemIndex);
        mAssocPage.mListPosition.nPosExtra=mList.getChildAt(mList.getChildCount()-1).getTop();
    }else{ // Force to top
        mAssocPage.mListPosition.selectionBase=null;
        mAssocPage.mListPosition.nPosExtra=0;
        mAssocPage.mListPosition.setAtBottom(nItemIndex>=mAssocPage.arrItems.size());
    }

}
```

If the listview is at top, scroll return function smoothly scrolls up to the top, if user is not scrolling the listview. +1 is used for `delta` is because mList have a header. In this case, arrItem does NOT lose any item, so 0<=nPos<=mList.arrItems.size() is guaranteed.

```
public void returnListPosition(){
    if(mAssocPage.mListPosition.bInitialized){
        int delta=mAdapter.getPaddingCount()+1;
        if(mAssocPage.mListPosition.isAtBottom()){
            mList.setSelection(mAssocPage.arrItems.size()+delta);
        }else{
            int nPos=mAssocPage.mListPosition.selectionBase==null?0:Collections.binarySearch(mAssocPage.arrItems, mAssocPage.mListPosition.selectionBase);
            if(nPos<0){
                nPos=-nPos+1;
                mList.setSelection(nPos+delta);
            }else{
                mList.setSelectionFromTop(nPos+delta, mAssocPage.mListPosition.nPosExtra);
            }
            if(mAssocPage.mListPosition.isAtTop() && !isScrolling()){ // Move to top
                mList.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                mAssocPage.mListPosition.nPosExtra=0;
                if(mAssocPage.arrItems.size()>0)
                    mAssocPage.mListPosition.selectionBase=mAssocPage.arrItems.get(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following function in mAssocList will modify old arrItems by replacing with modified arrItems (arrToReplace), and if the list is visible it'll scroll the list. To make sure the function is called one at a time, I used `synchronized`.

- `mAssocView` is the class extending `View` with above two functions.
- `notifyAssocView` will call adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged`.

The function will always be called with the function with one parameter.

From https://github.com/GaulSori/artwave/blob/master/src/gaulsori/artwave/items/SinglePage.java

```
private void applyTempEditor(final ArrayList<SpecialListItem> arrToReplace){
    applyTempEditor(arrToReplace, false);
}
private void applyTempEditor(final ArrayList<SpecialListItem> arrToReplace, boolean withoutSync){
    if(!withoutSync){
        synchronized(this){
            applyTempEditor(arrToReplace, true);
        }
        return;
    }
    if(mAssocView==null || mAssocView.getHandler()==null){
        arrItems=arrToReplace;
    }else if(Utils.isUiThread()){
        // FIXME Sometimes position returning does NOT work
        arrItems=arrToReplace;
        notifyAssocView();

        mAssocView.returnListPosition();
    }else{
        final Semaphore semp=new Semaphore(1);
        semp.drainPermits();
        if(mAssocView.getHandler().post(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {

            applyTempEditor(arrToReplace, true);

            semp.release();
            }})==false)
            throw new RuntimeException("?????");
        semp.acquireUninterruptibly(); // Wait for UI is actually changed
    }
}
```

`applyTempEditor` is frequently called in non-UI thread, and the scroll position would **sometimes be kept while sometimes not**. But then again, if the UI change is programically locked (if user is touching the screen), the change will be postponed until arrItems's modification is finished and after the user release the finger, the listview's position would be kept.

- `isUiLocked()` indicates if the user is tapping the screen or not.

Following code is to be run frequently in multiple non-UI threads.

```
if(isUiLocked()){
    return;
}
synchronized(this){
    arrItemsTempEditor=new ArrayList<SpecialListItem>(arrItems);
    applyNewItems(true, true, arrItemsTempEditor); // Modify arrItemsTempEditor ONLY
    applyTempEditor(arrItemsTempEditor); // Apply to arrItems
}
notifyAssocView();
```

I tried wrapping `returnListPosition` in `mList.post(new Runnable(){ @Override public void run(){ ... } });`, but I found no difference - the list sometimes won't scroll. I checked that the function is called everytime by adding `android.util.Log.d("artwave", "setSelectionFromTop")` in returnListPosition and `android.util.Log.d("artwave", "update")` in applyTempEditor. Since mListPosition is not modified outside onScroll, the scroll position returns to original position *eventually*, but it's still annoying to see scroll jumping. What can be the reason that setSelectionFromTop sometimes work and sometimes not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following function:

```
public void setListChanged(){
    mListChanged=true;
}
```

which makes sure that the list's adapter will be reset on next applyPageStatus() call.

```
public void applyPageStatus(){
    if(!Utils.isUiThread()){ // UI thread
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(HandlerMessages.MESSAGE_SINGLE_PAGE_APPLY_STATUS);
        return;
    }

    ...

    if(mListChanged){
        mList.setAdapter(null);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        returnListPosition();
    }
}
```

By removing the adapter and resetting, the listview will make changes to its children immediately. Thought this is inefficient since many Views have to be disposed on every operation, until I have another solution, I'll have to stick with this one.

Only fallback of this solution is that if the list was flinging, it would stop.